# Using GMock with Spring how to I setup up a spring context only once for several tests?

Tags: java, testing, groovy, tdd, gmock

I find that when running multiple [gmock](http://code.google.com/p/gmock/wiki/) tests using and in memory database I get errors about table already being there. It seems to run the spring context creation multiple times, even though it's only set once in a given test class as a field to be used by all the test methods.

Ideally I would like multiple classes to reuse the same context but even multiple methods with a single GMockTestCase are re creating the spring context.

Overriding Junit setup method doesn't help.

I find this behaviour unintuitive and incorrect but probably there's something I don't understand about how [gmock](http://code.google.com/p/gmock/wiki/) or groovy works

```
class MyTest extends GMockTestCase {

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring.test.xml")

def mockRequest = mock(RenderRequest)
def mockResponse = mock(RenderResponse)

void testHandleRequest() {

    mockRequest.getAttribute('javax.portlet.userinfo').returns(userInfo)
    mockRequest.getRemoteUser().returns(userName)

    play {
        def mav = mainController.handleRenderRequestInternal(mockRequest, mockResponse)
        assertEquals userName, mav.model.un
```

One workaround I can use for now but is not ideal is to use the annotated technique and extend a spring test class like this:

```
@WithGMock
@ContextConfiguration(locations = ["classpath:spring.dev.xml"])
class MyTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
```

Comment: Could you add some representative code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BeforeClass would allow you to construct one context per class

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/kontakteTest-portlet.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners(value = {DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
MockActionRequest request;
MockActionResponse response;

@Before
public final void init() {
    request = new MockActionRequest();
    response = new MockActionResponse();
}
```

and you can use them many time.